Error: NotFoundError - Resource not found while implementing llama index with Azure OpenAI for fine-tuning
Description:
During the implementation of the llama index with Azure OpenAI for fine-tuning, the following error occurred:
Retrying llama_index.llms.openai.base.OpenAI._chat in 0.6394267984578837 seconds as it raised NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}.

Code snippet:
# Perform query to retrieve the contexts and answers for the generated questions

self.llm = OpenAI(
    api_base=self.azure_openai_endpoint,
    api_key=self.azure_openai_api_key,
    api_version=self.azure_openai_api_version,
    model=self.model,
    temperature=self.temperature
)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=2, llm=self.llm)

Additional Information:
The error seems to be related to a NotFound error with code 404 indicating that the requested resource was not found.
Problem Statement:
The issue occurs while trying to execute the query using Azure OpenAI. The error message suggests that the resource being requested is not found.
Solution Required:
Please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue as I am unsure how to proceed.

Check this GitHub repo and steps.

There is separate python package for azure OpenAI integration.
So, create llm using AzureOpenAI.
First, install the integration package using below command.
%pip install llama-index-llms-azure-openai
Next, create llm.
from llama_index.llms.azure_openai import AzureOpenAI

aoai_api_key = "YOUR_AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"
aoai_endpoint = "YOUR_AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"
aoai_api_version = "2023-05-15"

llm = AzureOpenAI(
    model="YOUR_AZURE_OPENAI_COMPLETION_MODEL_NAME",
    deployment_name="YOUR_AZURE_OPENAI_COMPLETION_DEPLOYMENT_NAME",
    api_key=aoai_api_key,
    azure_endpoint=aoai_endpoint,
    api_version=aoai_api_version,
)

Use that llm while getting query engine.
Refer below documentation for more information.
Azure AI Search - LlamaIndex
Azure OpenAI - LlamaIndex
